# Jest coverage should not include rootDir in path, create mismatch with Cypress coverage

Tags: jestjs, cypress, istanbul

I need to merge Cypress coverage report and Jest coverage report, in the context of Next.js application.

Jest will list files as `my-app/src/whatever`. Cypress only shows `src/whatever`.

Cypress won't include `my-app` and Jest does, which raises issue when trying to merge coverage using recommended method from Cypress examples. The alternative would be to have Cypress to display the folder too.

#### Solution 1: Jest matches Cypress?

I'd like Jest to compute covered files path relative to the rootDir, without displaying it.

For example, the coverage report will show `my-app/src/whatever`. It should only show `src/whatever`, without `my-app`.

Is that doable?

#### Solution 2: Cypress matches Jest?

The alternative is to have Cypress considering another root dir, but I haven't found such options. It's the least promising option imo. Is there a relevant option for this?

Subsidiary question: both tools have a different line count, probably due to TypeScript + Babel + Webpack interactions with the code. How can I debug this issue?

Thanks

**Edit for clarity**

Comment: Can you not simply change the collectCoverageFrom glob to be src/**, and leave the reference to rootDir out?

Comment: From the Cypress end, there's a path adjustment happening [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage/blob/e4b9698c5fa89145dea2ad5fcfdbd3b30103a05b/task.js#L76). You could substitute your own version of the `combineCoverage(sentCoverage)` task by adding it after the code-coverage package, and within that make a different path adjustment with your own version of `fixSourcePaths()`. To be sure I'd need a repo to test it on.

Comment: @StevenScott You are right if the code is located in a `src` folder. However Next.js don't have a separate `src` folder as a default for instance (moving code to src was indeed a quickfix for me). I'd be glad to find a more generic solution to this issue, say for example when you have two folder, imagine `src` and `legacySrc` for some reason.

Comment: @RichardMatsen ok so basically the issue here is that Cypress is doing some magic with path that Jest just don't?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell from the code of `fixSourcePaths()`, but the comments say it does two things 1) change relative paths to absolute 2) remove webpack related stuff. You mention you're looking for the opposite (absolute to relative paths), or are you just looking for consistency between Cypress coverage and Jest coverage? Since the Cypress package aims to merge the those, they should already be consistent. You should flesh out some details in your question.

Comment: With mutiple aths, the collectCoverageFrom is a glob, so you list multiple paths if needed.  You can also use negative to skip paths (!path/to/skip)

Comment: Edited for clarity, thanks for your suggestions. Multiple paths for `collectCoverageFrom` forces me to list each valid folder. You could probably make this comment an answer but only as a quickfix. Also then the folder name might not appear (eg `["components/*.ts"/, "pages/*.ts"]` will strip the folder name to keep only the files name) so that may not work in the end.

Answer (score 2):

As a quickfix specific to Next, using an `src` folder is now doable in Next. So putting all testable code in an isolated folder can be a quickfix.

In your Jest config:

```js
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ...
```

(not sure why but Cypress do not seem to need aditional config when adding an `src` folder)

Comment: And to ignore directories, prefix with `!`. Example: `!**/node_modules/**`